# Swift 4 Unit Testing with Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, core-data

I have an iOS project that is working fine on the simulator and whatnot, but cannot seem to link up nicely to the Core Data resources when I'm working from its testing bundle.

I've made the `NSManagedObjectContext` from memory in the set-up function of my testing class. However, when I attempt to run the program, the test functions fail, and the console has output

```
"An NSManagedObject of class 'Projectname.Deck' must have a valid NSEntityDescription."
```

Is there something I'm missing? I'd like to be able to make unit tests for my app's data structure as I develop it.

Thanks!

Edit

Relevant sections of the test class:

```
class ProjectNameTests: XCTestCase {

var testDeck: Deck? = nil

    func setUpInMemoryManagedObjectContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
    let managedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModel(from: [Bundle.main])!

    let persistentStoreCoordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: managedObjectModel)

    do {
        try persistentStoreCoordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSInMemoryStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: nil, options: nil)
    } catch {
        print("Adding in-memory persistent store failed")
    }

    let managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = persistentStoreCoordinator

    return managedObjectContext
}//setUpInMemoryManagedObjectContext

override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()

    self.context = setUpInMemoryManagedObjectContext()
    testDeck = Deck(context: context)
    testDeck!.name = "Test Deck"
}//setUp
}//ProjectNameTests
```

Comment: show the code for the class and test you have, show us what you got and we can help out, there isn't enough info here to give you an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
After doing a fair bit of research, I was able to figure out that my issue was related to pulling the `NSEntityDescription` from the class itself, and not from the current context.

I added the following method to my Deck class (and will do the same for other `NSManagedObject` subclasses):

```
public static func entityDescription(context: NSManagedObjectContext)->NSEntityDescription{
    return NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: String(describing: self), in: context)!
}//entityDescription
```

I then changed the initialization call in my test case to the following:

```
let deckEntity: NSEntityDescription = Deck.entityDescription(context: context)
testDeck = Deck(entity: deckEntity, insertInto: context)
```

This way, the object is initialized with the `NSEntityDescription` pulled from the current `NSManagedObjectContext`, which makes everything happier.

Props to [Swift, Core Data, and unit testing](https://www.jessesquires.com/blog/swift-coredata-and-testing/) for leading me on the right track.